# file created in sd card missing?

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

am using this this code to create and write a file on sd card, but after running my android app, i can't seem to find any file created in the sd card. i'm not sure whether there is something wrong with my codes or what. please help me. any comments would be greatly appreciated..thank you!

**here's the code i'm using:**

```
   private void writeToSDFile() {


    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
    tv.append("\nExternal file system root: "+root);



    File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath());
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "wordlist.txt");

    try {       



        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);


        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        pw.println(stringword);
        pw.append(stringword);


        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        f.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, "******* File not found.);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    tv.append("\n\nFile written to "+file);

}//end writeToSDFile
```

Comment: Any error displayed? Do you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing seems wrong in your code, you have to make sure of two things:

1- You have appropriate permission in your manifest i.e.`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

2- The external storage is `mounted` e.g.

```
if(Environment.getExternalStorageState() == Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED){
    // write your file
}
```

You have redundancy in your code, the line `File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath());` is absolutely useless.

All what you need is:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "wordlist.txt");
```

Comment: i have written the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest, however, what i have observed is that the directory shown in my txtView is mnt/sdcard/.What does this mean?

Comment: Thank you for your response, i believe i have the problem about the sd card mount. i'll try to get it work now.thank you @iTech =)